# How to fadeOut & fadeIn values of array infinite times?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to apply `fadeOut` current one(50 milliseconds), and `fadeIn` next one(500 milliseconds) during **iterating** the array infinite times (every 3000 milliseconds I want to this event occurs).

I searched some of related topics with this, but I was not able to find suitable one with mine.

Here is my code

```js
var names = ["Mina","Minaming","Minami","HelloMina"];
var says = ["hello 1", "hello 2", "hello 3", "hello 4"];

function display(arg, arr){
    $(arg).html(arr[0]);
  
    var i = 1;
    setInterval(
      function(){
        $(arg).html(arr[i]);

        i++;
        if(i >= arr.length) i = 0;
    },3000);
}

display($('#career'), names);
display($('#saying'), says);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="career"></div>
<div id="saying"></div>
```

and Here is `jsfiddle` Example. http://jsfiddle.net/tjAa6/118/

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```js
var names = ["Mina", "Minaming", "Minami", "HelloMina"];
var says = ["hello 1", "hello 2", "hello 3", "hello 4"];

function display(arg, arr) {
  $(arg).html(arr[0]);

  var i = 1;
  setInterval(function() {
    $(arg).fadeOut(50, 'linear', function() {
      $(arg).html(arr[i]).fadeIn(100);
      i++;
    });
    if (i >= arr.length) i = 0;
  }, 3000);
}
display($('#career'), names);
display($('#saying'), says);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="career"></div>
<div id="saying"></div>
```

I hope to be helpful for you :)

Comment: Your welcome:). also I recommend you to read (https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_fadein.asp) page which explains fade functions very well.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation too!

Answer (score 0):

```
var names = ["Mina","Minaming","Minami","HelloMina"];
var says = ["hello 1", "hello 2", "hello 3", "hello 4"];

function display(arg, arr){
    $(arg).html(arr[0]);

  var i = 1;
  setInterval(
    function(){
    $(arg).fadeOut(function() {
      $(arg).html(arr[i]);
      i++;
      if(i >= arr.length) i = 0;
      $(arg).fadeIn();
    });
        $(arg).fadeOut();    
    },3000);
}

display($('#career'), names);
display($('#saying'), says);
```

I tested it. Thank you for reading carefully.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But nothing happens with it... https://jsfiddle.net/4r43r25k/